# SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure", ...] with NMaximize

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, error-tracking

I have a complicated analytical expression that needs to be maximized with respect to a parameter `t`:

```
qfB[t_,\[Lambda]_,\[Gamma]_,a_]=Uncompress["1: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"];
```

For certain values of the parameters, for example with the following command

```
NMaximize[{qfB[t, 1, 2, 0.5162124455872646`], t > 0}, t][[1]]
```

I obtain the following error

```
SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure", {NMaximize[{qfB[t, 1, 2, 
  0.516212], t > 0}, t][[1]], OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[52], -1 + 4.5*10^-24300380321879}]
```

(very long output, even if compressed). This error doesn't appear in the documentation, and it causes the whole evaluation to stop.

I would like to understand why it comes up, and if there is a way around it or at least a way to handle it inside a computation.

**EDIT**

Following Oleksandr's suggestion I have filed a support request to Wolfram technical support and it has been forwarded to the developers as a bug.

Comment: I got this as a Maximized answer after several trials, `{0.0175048, {t -> 0.570513}}`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for your comment. I'll investigate the analytical form of my function to fix the numerical instability. I've noticed that `FindMaximum` can be slow for certain parameters. I will try with `NelderMeadMinimize`.

Comment: The kernel crashes after a minute in V10.1 (Mac OSX, Macbook Pro, 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB RAM).  Does that count as the bug being "fixed"? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error should probably be reported to WRI as a bug, most likely in `` Experimental`NumericalFunction ``; you should not be seeing this come back up to the top level. I see no obvious reason why memory allocation should fail, as this is not really a large or difficult problem, despite the apparent complexity of the expression.

However, we do not really need the full global optimization machinery of `NMaximize` anyway, as the function is seen to be unimodal by plotting. Thus, we can manage with only local minimizers.

For what it's worth, neither `FindMaximum` or `NelderMeadMinimize` have a problem with this function--so it seems confined to `NMinimize`:

```
FindMaximum[{qfB[t, 1, 2, 0.5162124455872646`], t > 0}, {t, 1}]
(* -> { 0.017504782445427220`, {t -> 0.5705059672138650`}} *)

NelderMeadMinimize[-qfB[t, 1, 2, 0.5162124455872646`], t]
(* -> {-0.017504782449431693`, {t -> 0.5705132464216982`}} *)
```

If `FindMaximum` seems too slow, it's probably because it starts too close to $t=0$, where the expression diverges. This causes overflows and other numerical problems, which `FindMaximum` may attempt to deal with by ramping up the precision. Constrained optimization is also slower than unconstrained, although constraints are not really necessary here. We can fix any problem `FindMaximum` has by giving it a more favorable starting region:

```
FindMaximum[qfB[t, 1, 2, 0.5162124455872646`25], {t, 1/2, 1}]
(* -> {0.017504782449430056`, {t -> 0.5705133885275231`}} *)
```

This way is about 100 times faster than using the constraint, and actually a bit (~30%) faster even than `NelderMeadMinimize`, using the *Mathematica* VM. (`NelderMeadMinimize` is faster when using a C compiler, but most compilers will take a long time to compile this complicated expression, so there is no benefit unless you need to maximize this for very many combinations of parameters.)

Comment: I have reported the problem with the error message to Wolfram. I've also tried your `NelderMeadMinimize` function and it works great, much faster than `FindMaximum`!

Comment: @Pincopallino if they confirm it is a bug, could you please update the question to add the "bugs" tag? Also, see my update about the poor performance of `FindMaximum`. Even though `NelderMeadMinimize` can be a bit faster, personally I think the difference is not large enough to be worth bothering with; just use `FindMaximum` without the constraint instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can get:

```
qfB = Uncompress["You expression here"];
myfun = qfB /. {\[Lambda] -> 1., \[Gamma] -> 2., a -> 0.5162124455872646`} // N;
(* so that the expression only involves t *)

NMaximize[{myfun, t > 0}, t]
```

> {0.0175048, {t -> 0.570513}}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! However, I would like to understand the source of the error, because it appears to be undocumented. Does the error appear on you system?

Comment: @Pincopallino I had a similar error once. If I use your code, I got the same error as yours. I think it is just that the expression is too 'complicated' for MMA to handle. Sometimes, we have to give MMA a 'minimal' things to calculate. In this case, I have fixed other parameters before passing it on to `NMaximize`.