# Is this caused by meomory usage ? (Something odd/hard to describe)

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review

I really can't make a "smaller" example, but the files are here, for the [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3FvBqE2BCLXY2R1VFRtRW0tOHM&authuser=0) and for the [notebook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3FvBqE2BCLXWW9Cc0dYWVl1QVU&authuser=0). It will cost a LOT of memory, up to 30G of RAM (maybe more).

Here is the problem, (from a Linux Server, MMA10.0.2 X64)

[image]

It does look like it finished the job. But `res` did not save as expected.
I think this rise from a memory problem? Because at some point, the server(system) hang for a while.

Instead, if I use

```
(res = ParallelTable[
     myclosepop[dat[indat], kdat[indat], m], {indat, data}, {m, models}
 ];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

`res` will finish and save without any problem. The memory usage during the calculation will also be "smaller".

My main question is:

1 - can the code be improved to avoid this?
2 - What does the error message tell me?? `Join::heads:......` does really not tell me much. I did not use it explicitly. And I dont even know whether this is a memory related problem.

Thanks!

Update: Individual ones do run OK, say with a smaller subsets of the models

[image]

I am doing in this way, hoping to get a "nice" table, with **all results** in it.

Comment: What happens if you run a subset of the data/models, or use `Table` instead of `ParallelTable`?

Comment: Single ones do run fine, even with different methods and search points ect. But I want to make a nice table like this, say run `models = {"Bin", "BetaBin"};` then the `res = ....` then `{lmax, aics, mles} = Transpose[res, {2, 3, 1}];
TableForm[lmax, TableHeadings -> {data, models}]`. These gives an informative table, see updated post.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are running into the same issue as was reported [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70120/systemexceptionmemoryallocationfailure-with-nmaximize). A possible workaround is to give `NMinimize` an explicit `PostProcess` option value, e.g.`"PostProcess" -> {"KKT"}` (this goes inside the `Method` option setting).

Comment: I will try and see if that works. I have also updated the post, explaining why I am doing this. I will report the result back tomorrow.

Comment: I think the same problem still occur. On the server, the memory usage quickly goes up to about 40G and the process become a status "D" (it hangs basically).