# Error SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] when using FindMinimum and NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, special-functions

```
 mpi = 140;fpi = 92;EK[k_] := EllipticE[k^2]/EllipticK[k^2]; x[T_] := mpi/(T*fpi); kp[k_] := Sqrt[1 - k^2];

ECSL0[k_, muB_] := 
  N[2*(1 - 1/k^2 + 2/k^2 EK[k]) - (fpi*muB)/(
    4 Pi*mpi*k*EllipticK[k^2]), 20];
FT0[k_, lamRG_] := 
  N[mpi^2/(fpi^2*24*
     Pi^2)*((-3/(2 k^4) + 9/(4 k^2) - 3/4)*1/Sqrt[1 - k^2] - 13/(
      6 k^4) + 13/(6 k^2) + 3/4*Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 - k^2])/k] + 
      EK[k]*(Sqrt[1 - k^2]/k^4 + 17/(3 k^4) - 17/(6 k^2)) - 
      3/k^4 EK[k]^2
      + (-2/k^4 + 2/k^2 + (2/k^4 - 1/k^2) EK[k])*
       Log[(2 k)/(1 + Sqrt[1 - k^2])*lamRG/mpi]), 20];
FT[k_, T_] := 
  fpi^2/mpi^2*
   T^4*(N[-x[T]/(
       4 Pi*k*EllipticK[k^2])*(PolyLog[3, E^(-kp[k]/k*x[T])] + 
         kp[k]/k x[T]*PolyLog[2, E^(-kp[k]/k*x[T])]), 20]
     - 1/(2 Pi^2)
       NIntegrate[
       t^2*Log[1 - E^(-Sqrt[t^2 + x[T]^2])], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 20]
     - x[T]^3/(2 Pi^2*k)*
      NIntegrate[
       t*Log[1 - 
          E^(-(x[T]/k) Sqrt[1 + k^2 t^2])]*((EK[k] - 1) EllipticF[
            ArcTan[t], 1 - k^2] + EllipticE[ArcTan[t], 1 - k^2] - 
          t*Sqrt[(1 + k^2 t^2)/(1 + t^2)]), {t, 0, Infinity}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 20]
     - (x[T]^3*kp[k]^2)/(2 Pi^2*k^3)*
      NIntegrate[
       t*Log[1 - 
          E^(-((kp[k]*x[T]*t)/k))]*((1 - EK[k]) EllipticF[ArcSin[t], 
            1 - k^2] - EllipticE[ArcSin[t], 1 - k^2]), {t, 0, 1}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 20]);

Ftot[k_, T_, muB_, lamRG_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, Abs[k - 1] < 10^(-10)}, {(Abs[k] - 1), 
     Abs[k] >= 1 + 10^(-10)}}, 
   ECSL0[k, muB] + FT0[k, lamRG] + FT[k, T]];

FindMinimum[Ftot[k, 1.9, 70.717547464412`, mpi/2], {k, 0.8}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20];
```

I have a complicated function `Ftot` (including `NIntegrate`) that I would like to minimize with respect to `k` for a range of other parameters (`T`,`muB`,`lamRG`). But for some parameter values I get a message `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`. It is very strange, for example for the numbers I mention in the last line of the code, I get this error, but if I put 71 as the third input parameter of `Ftot`, I get a reasonable answer.

`k` has a meaning of elliptic modulus, i.e., `0<=k<=1` is expected (so that Ftot is real), but I have learned from one of the answers here ([SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure", ...] with NMaximize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70120/systemexceptionmemoryallocationfailure-with-nmaximize)) that unconstrained minimization should be quicker (and it indeed is for some parameters), so I better redefined the function `Ftot` to give also real number for `k>1`. Often, the minimum should be at `k=1`, so the redefinition is such that `Ftot` is growing for `k>1`, I hoped that this will help (and it did for some parameter values). I have also increased the WorkingPrecision, since the function `Ftot` is changing rapidly close to `k=1` (it behaves as `1/Log[1-k]`). It also helped in some cases, but there are still parameter values where I am getting the error message.

After some more research, I have found out that the error `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]` appears also in some of the `NIntegrate` routines included in the funciton `Ftot` (for certain parameter choice), for example, if I put

`NIntegrate[t^2*Log[1 - E^(-Sqrt[t^2 + x[T]^2])] /. T -> 0.1, {t, 0, Infinity},  WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

I am using Mathematica 11.3 (Mathematica 12 is very unstable on my computer for some reason).

Comment: The code above produces a reasonable answer in V12.2. I don't have V11.3. Since the code doesn't call `NMinimize`, the title is confusing: Are you having trouble with a different code that calls `NMinimize` or are you having trouble with `FindMinimum`? -- That aside, you'll get fewer warning if you redefine `Ftot` like this: `ClearAll[Ftot]; Ftot[k_?NumericQ, T_, muB_, lamRG_] :=...`.  You can get rid of more by calling `FindMinimum` like this: ``Block[{$MinPrecision = 20, $MaxPrecision = 20}, FindMinimum[Ftot[k, 1.9`20, 70.717547464412`20, mpi/2], {k, 0.8`20}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] ]``